# Compare R.id to int

Tags: android, compare

I am building an simple Android app am looking for a way to compare number input to a pre-stored integer. My first though was:

```
if(R.id.number == 123456){
}
```

This comparison does not work. I have also tried .equals, with no avail. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to compare the two values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `R.id.number` refers to a `View`'s id (most likely an `EditText` since you say you are comparing user input). Thus, comparing *that* to a number would definitely not be what you're looking for. Find the `EditText` via `findViewById()`, parse its text into an integer and compare that.

Eg

```
public void onCreate (Bundle b){
  super.onCreate (b);

  EditText e = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.number);

  int num = 0;

  try{
    num = Integer.parseInt (e.getText().toString().trim());
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e){
  }

  if (num == 123456){
    System.out.println ("Input equal");
  }
}
```